# How do I hold numbers after rolling dice rnadomly so I can reroll the dice but not all of them? C# (badly worded sorry)

Tags: c#, command-line, dice

I'm working on a dice game assignment where I am re-rolling dice in hope to find a 3 of a kind or a 4 of a kind, etc out of 6 dice. But if you roll a two of kind, I wanted to hold those values and re-roll to find a 3,4,5 of a kind. I am struggling to figure out how to make the program hold the values while re-rolling the others without completely re-rolling everything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

class die
{

    // attributes

    private int numberOnTop;
    private Random randomNumberGenerator;

    // methods
    // roll the die, get the number currently showing on top

    public die(Random randomGenerator)
    {
        //initialise the random number generator
        randomNumberGenerator = randomGenerator;
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        //create a random number from 1 to 6 and store it in the numberOnTop attribute

        numberOnTop = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 7);
    }


    public int getNumberOnTop()
    {
        // a "get" method to get the value of the number currently on top and return the value to where the call was made

        return numberOnTop;
    }

}


class diceGame
{
    //main program


    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Int32 UserSelect;
        int playerone = 0;
        int playertwo = 0;
        int playeroneturn = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my two person dice game. Would you like to play \r\n 1. Person vs Person \r\n 2. Person vs AI");
        UserSelect = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //  A switch will select which option that the user input using the Value Selected variable
            switch (UserSelect)
            {
                case 1:

                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is players 1's turn");

                    //create a random number generator to pass to the die objects
                    Random myRandomiser = new Random();


                    die[] myDie = new die[6];
                    //instantiate the three dice (the constructor is called)

                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {

                        myDie[i] = new die(myRandomiser);

                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                    {
                        myDie[i].roll();

                        switch (myDie[i].getNumberOnTop())
                        {
                            case 1:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n |         |\r\n |    O    |\r\n |         |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n | O       |\r\n |         |\r\n |       O |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n | O       |\r\n |    O    |\r\n |       O |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n | O     O |\r\n |         |\r\n | O     O |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n | O     O |\r\n |    O    |\r\n | O     O |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;

                            case 6:
                                Console.WriteLine("  ---------\r\n | O     O |\r\n | O     O |\r\n | O     O |\r\n  ---------");
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    // two of a kind check goes here and therefore the rerolls will happen here

                    var twoofakind = new[] { myDie[0].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[1].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[2].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[3].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[4].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[5].getNumberOnTop() };

                    var isLargeGroupTwo = twoofakind.GroupBy(n => n, (key, group) => group.Count())
                    .Any(count => count >= 2);

                    if (isLargeGroupTwo == true) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please reroll to try and get a 3, 4, or 5 of a kind");
                        if (myDie[0].getNumberOnTop() == myDie[1].getNumberOnTop())
                        {
                            int i = 2;
                            myDie[i].roll();

                        }
                    }

                    // ends here


                    var threeofakind = new[] { myDie[0].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[1].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[2].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[3].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[4].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[5].getNumberOnTop() };

                    //three of a kind check

                    var isLargeGroupThree = threeofakind.GroupBy(n => n, (key, group) => group.Count())
                    .Any(count => count >= 3);
                    Console.WriteLine("Is there any 3 of a kind's in the roll?");
                    Console.WriteLine(isLargeGroupThree);

                    if (isLargeGroupThree == true)
                    {
                        playerone = playerone + 3;
                        Console.WriteLine("Player one has scored a 3 of a kind therefore earning 3 points.");
                        Console.WriteLine(playerone);

                    }
                    else if (isLargeGroupThree == false)
                    {
                        var fourofakind = new[] { myDie[0].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[1].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[2].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[3].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[4].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[5].getNumberOnTop() };
                        //four of a kind check
                        var isLargeGroupFour = fourofakind.GroupBy(n => n, (key, group) => group.Count())
                        .Any(count => count >= 4);
                        Console.WriteLine("Is there any 4 of a kind's in the roll?");
                        Console.WriteLine(isLargeGroupFour);
                        if (isLargeGroupFour == true)
                        {
                            playerone = playerone + 6;
                            Console.WriteLine("Player one has scored a 4 of a kind therefore earning 6 points.");
                            Console.WriteLine("Player one's total score is" + playerone);

                        }
                        else if (isLargeGroupFour == false)
                        {
                            var fiveofakind = new[] { myDie[0].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[1].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[2].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[3].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[4].getNumberOnTop(), myDie[5].getNumberOnTop() };
                            //four of a kind check
                            var isLargeGroupFive = fiveofakind.GroupBy(n => n, (key, group) => group.Count())
                            .Any(count => count >= 5);
                            Console.WriteLine("Is there any 5 of a kind's in the roll?");
                            Console.WriteLine(isLargeGroupFive);
                            if (isLargeGroupFive == true)
                            {
                                playerone = playerone + 12;
                                Console.WriteLine("Player one has scored a 5 of a kind therefore earning 12 points.");
                                Console.WriteLine("Player two's total score is" + playerone);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
                } while (playerone < 50);

                Console.WriteLine("Player one has reached 50 points in " + playeroneturn + "turns");
                 break;
            }
        }
  }
```

I will keep working at it but any help with this will be really great :)

Comment: Start putting code outside the do-while loop. For example: Random myRandomiser = new Random();

Answer (score 0):

Inside your two of a kind check:

```
if (isLargeGroupTwo == true) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please reroll to try and get a 3, 4, or 5 of a kind");
                    if (myDie[0].getNumberOnTop() == myDie[1].getNumberOnTop())
                    {
                        for(int i = 2; i < 6; i++)
                            myDie[i].roll();
```

This might work.